# Defining unpacking format with python's struct

Tags: python, struct, unpack

I'm trying to unpack a binary file with python's struct.unpack.
when i write struct.unpack("200i",data) it works.
but when i want to use a number of integers found in a previous operation like this: struct.unpack("a[1]i",data) it doesn't work.

p.s: a[1]=200

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert it to string for the function to work:

```
struct.unpack(str(a[1]) + "i",data)
```

Comment: Thank you; it's workin. I have another question if you don't mind:

Comment: No problem. Go ahead